# Post via user define device

Tags: facebook

When a user post through an app, the post as an identifier like "via UpdateStatus".
There are some funny apps that allow to customize this field and you can send post via a Potato, Hogwarts Letters etc.

I found out that to do this you have to create an app with every different name you want.

My question is can you define this field programmatically? Just create an app and mask only this field when posting in Facebook wall.

I have discover that there is a field application in post where you can define app name and id. I don't want to change the id, only the name.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

Is this possible to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

> My question is can you define this field programmatically?

No, you can’t. It’s *always* the name of your app.

> I have discover that there is a field application in post where you can define app name and id.

That’s the information you get when *reading* a post object. That does not mean you can *set* it while posting.